# getText doesn't work (website localization)

Tags: php, html, gettext

I'm trying to make a website localizable in multiple language. I'm using XAMPP to test translations. The problem is that the string "Text not translated" does not change and I have already tried multiple solutions. I already modified the string into php.ini which enables/disables the gettext function. Here is my test website project:

```
htdocs/Traduzioni/Locale/it-IT/LC_MESSAGES/
```

Under LC_MESSAGES there are 2 files named:
- messages.po;
- messages.mo

```
<?php
   $language = "it-it";
   putenv("LANG=".$language);
   setlocale(LC_ALL, $language);

   $domain = "messages";
   bindtextdomain($domain, "C:\xampp\htdocs\Traduzioni\Locale");
   textdomain($domain);

   echo gettext("Text not translated");
?>
```

^ This is the content of the index.php file contained into Traduzioni folder.

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: \n"
"PO-Revision-Date: \n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language-Team: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Language: it_IT\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 2.0.7\n"

# Test1
msgid "Text not translated"
msgstr "Testo tradotto"
```

^ And this is the content of the messages.po file under the it-it folder.

I already tried to restart Apache and tried the `function_exists` function to make sure that the package is installed correcly.

I'm running this server on Windows (10). Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You're going to have a bad time with this on Windows... I'm pretty sure it hasn't worked for a few years.

Comment: Hmmm though actually there's a comment on the [gettext](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php) page on the PHP manual from one month ago about getting it to work on Windows, pointing to a [gettext/iconv Windows installer](https://mlocati.github.io/articles/gettext-iconv-windows.html) ... so maybe there's hope afterall!

Comment: Thanks a lot @CD001! I moved my website on Linux and it works. Thanks a lot again :)

Comment: Warning: gettext is basically broken on Windows when running as Apache module. Even if you manage to make it work, you'll find other issues later. It's fine if you'll deploy to a Linux server though.